# MongoDb - select collections and indexes by column

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am making first steps in NoSQL and have the following question:

Say we have several collections in the database with the field named "EmployeeNumber".

How would I write a script to select all the collection names which have this field and also all the index names which are using this column?

Comment: Mongodb does not have columns. Colums are a property of SQL. Mongodb stores documents with varying schemas.

Comment: Sorry I mean fields. Fixed the post.

Comment: Iterate over all the collections and check each one for what you're looking for. Doc here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Collections don't have Schemas, so you could check all the collections to see if they contain a record with a property of `EmployeeNumber` but that would be terrible.

If you wanted to it would look something like:

```
function findCollectionsWithEmployeeNumber(cb){
    var collectionsWithEmployeeNumber = [];
    var collectionsToCheck = {};
    db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
        collections.forEach(function(c){collectionsToCheck[c]=false});
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        collections.forEach(function(collection){
            db[collection].findOne({EmployeeNumber : {$exists :true}}, function(err, res){
                if(res) {
                    collectionsWithEmployeeNumber.push(collection);
                }
                collectionsToCheck[collection] = true;
                var allChecked = collectionsToCheck.reduce(function(previous, current){return previous && current}, true)
                if(allChecked) {
                    cb(collectionsWithEmployeeNumber);
                }
            })
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer: 1. You can't. 2. Well, you could but it would be terrible. 3. Ok, let me write it for you. :-)